# Content-Length PHP Header. Right way to calculate it

Tags: php

I need to send a XML file encoded in base64 and others data inside a variable `$content`.
I'm not sure Content-Length is calculated in the right way cause my webservice tell me there's an error (Invalid parameters input). I'm sure file sended is correct. So my only doubt is the lenght calculated?

This is my script:

```
$base64 = base64_encode(file_get_contents("file.xml"));

$post = "/services/invoice/upload";

$content = array(
    "dataFile" => $base64,
    "credential" => "",
    "domain" => ""
);

try {

    $ch = curl_init();

    $header = array(
        "Content-type: application/json;charset=UTF-8",
        "Accept: application/json",
        "Authorization: Bearer nfsedkvcsjocnso", //token
        "Content-Length:" . strlen(json_encode($content)), //
        "Host: localhost:8080"
      );

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://xxxxxxx.com" . $post);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($content));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    // receive server response



    $server_output = curl_exec($ch);

    if ($server_output === false) {
        throw new Exception(curl_error($ch), curl_errno($ch));
    }

    var_dump($server_output);

    curl_close($ch);

} catch(Exception $e) {

    trigger_error(sprintf('Curl failed with error #%d: %s',$e->getCode(), $e->getMessage()), E_USER_ERROR);

}
```

This is specification by WS (example):

```
POST /services/invoice/upload HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
Authorization: Bearer NLOGDVXLVaF3tzmnVPkTwpkuh7dG0i09uSCcog3u+rE=
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 90
Host: localhost:8080

{
  "dataFile" : "dGVzdA==",
  "credential" : "cred_firma", //can be empty
  "domain" : "dom_firma" //can be empty
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure curl sets the `Content-Length` header, so you don't need to do it yourself.

Comment: Just don't send it and tools will calculate it automatically

Comment: Don't encode the data two times. Also I think the problem is not the content length, seems to be a parameter in the data itself.